# Best Practice: Separate Tables for Separate Info on Same User

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am designing a database for student information. I wish to implement the best practices regarding separate tables and use of `Primary and Foreign Keys`.

Let's say I have the following tables (High Level):

- Users
- Student Information
- Student Transcripts
- Student Records

There will be different users with different levels. Also, the information in Student Info/Transcripts/Records will all have a `Foreign Key` with the ID that's in Users.

SO, it would be dumb to just clump all the tables into one big table, wouldn't it? Is it a good idea to keep all this information separate and just use Primary/Foreign keys to link things together, as well as maybe Joins? I just personally think a big table would be quite messy and through this way, it allows one to keep similar data together with its own kind.

Thanks for all input on the matter!

Comment: Without understanding the columns in each of these tables, and knowing if a user could have a multitude of information, or its layout, this question is near impossible to answer.  There's too many unknowns about the data itself, how it is going to be used, or if it needs to be able to be scaled in the future.

Comment: Coincidentally, there are 6 columns in each of the Student tables. The info table has stuff like what their major is and their adviser. The Transcripts table has the classes they've taken and what they made in them and when they took them (it's mostly a static table). The Records table is the dynamic version of that, where it shows what they've taken, if it's been completed, if they've had a substitute, adviser notes. I mean to me, I feel that the tables are best apart. But I wonder if there are ever cases where there are huge tables with many columns of information and if that's a bad thing.

Comment: Work out your tables relationships.  If 1 user always has 1 student information record and that one student information record must always exist for one user, then it's probably best in the same table.  If a user can have multiple student information records, then a 1 to many relationship is appropriate and the tables should be seperate (i assume 1 user can have multiple transcripts?).  Keeping the future use of this model in mind, define each relationship here and if it's 1 to 1 or 1 to many (or many to many?)...you should be able to determine your data model setup from there

Comment: Your on the right track. The clue is Student Information is not plural so it should be unique with a primary key.  Student Transcripts and Student Records should have a foreign key constraint to Student Information.  The second clue is Users not Students.  I wouldn't know what to do here.  Need more specs.

Comment: Database design would tell you to keep data normalized.  Reduce data duplication (I didn't say eliminate because some duplication is valuable and at times needed), like constructs should be placed together.  So having 4 separate tables in this case makes sense, I can't see having it all in one table.